# Javascript FB.ui for feed dialog omits image & description.

Tags: javascript, facebook

I notice that now, `FB.ui` appears to open the Facebook App for sharing. Problem is it omits the image/description etc. Is there a way to fix this?

```
   FB.ui({
        app_id: facebookAppId,
        display: 'iframe',
        method: 'feed',
        link: hostUrl,
        caption: '...',
        description: caption,
        picture: '.../logo.jpg'
    }, function(response){});
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture must be an absolute URL, not a relative one. The description should work, but i guess you did not specify the variable "caption".

Example:

```
FB.ui({
        app_id: facebookAppId,
        display: 'iframe',
        method: 'feed',
        link: hostUrl,
        caption: '...',
        description: 'some description',
        picture: 'http://yourdomain.com/logo.jpg'
    }, function(response){});
```